# Python TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python

I have a below code written to get the Speed of the current running interface on the Linux but when i'm running this script its just throwing the error : `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings` .

would appreciate any help or ideas.

> Below is the script:

In the Below script i have 2 functions created 
1) The one is `get_Inf()` which gives the Interface information.
2) The Second One is `get_intSpeed()` which takes the interface name from the First functon and pass it the os command `ethtool` which further parsed in via a regex to Fetch only the Speed like `1000Mb/s`.

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.10/bin/python
import subprocess
import netifaces
import re

''' This snippet is just to get the Speed of the running interface on the System '''



def get_Inf():
    Current_inf = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][1]
    return get_Inf

def get_intSpeed():
    spd = subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/ethtool', get_Inf()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    pat_match=re.search(".*Speed:\s+(\d+Mb/s)\s+.*", spd)       # "d" means any number of digit following the "Mb/s".
    speed = pat_match.group(1)
    return speed

def main():
    print get_intSpeed()


main()
```

> Below is the os command `/sbin/ethtool` which has the Speed
>   information of the Interface along with Other Information.

```
[root@tss /]# /sbin/ethtool eth0| grep Speed
              Speed: 1000Mb/s
[root@tss /]# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Link detected: yes
```

I am using python version 2.7.10.

Comment: Please show the whole error. The code you posted does not call `execv`. At least, not directly.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thanks for your feedback, i realized that i am returing wrong   values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_Inf()` function will return itself with the `return get_Inf` statement, which is not a string, that is why `execv` (which is called by `subprocess.Popen`) is complaining. You should return `Current_Inf` from your function.

Comment: Albert P, thanks for the catch indeed. Though i realized that .